# postgres text field to numeric with empty and null values

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, casting

Postgres 10.8

I have a JSON field in my Database which includes a price if there is one.

I get the values like this:

```
select t.config::jsonb ->> 'price' as price from mytable t
```

It gives me the following results back (null,empty and a price) as a textformat:

```
[null],'',1330.0
```

I need to be able to make this field numeric so that I can sum this field later on.

I've tried to solve it like this:

```
select 
(
case 
when t.config::jsonb ->> 'price' is null then '0.00'
when t.config::jsonb ->> 'price' = '' then '0.00'
else t.config::jsonb ->> 'price' 
end)::decimal as price 
from mytable t
```

This gives me a numeric(131089,0) back. I want the field to be like numeric(10,2). There must be a other easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions `nullif` and `coalesce` can be very handy in this case. `nullif(value,'')` returns `null` in case value is empty and `coalesce(value,'0.00')` returns `0.00` in case value is `null`, so you might wanna chain both functions like this:

```
SELECT 
 coalesce(nullif(t.config::jsonb ->> 'price',''),'0.00')::numeric(10,2) as price 
FROM mytable t;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=362ac236a540f6ad6e2f21add655bf67)

Comment: Yes it gives me the same output but much less code thanks! I still wonder over one thing though. In dbeaver when i hoover over other numeric fields in the table it says numeric(10,2) but if i hoover over this one it says numeric(131089,0)???

Comment: @user2210516 did you see my last edit? `SELECT 
 coalesce(nullif(t.config::jsonb ->> 'price',''),'0.00')::numeric(10,2) as price 
FROM mytable t;`